# Data missing in multiple View in RecyclerView using retrofit response

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, retrofit, multiview

I am facing an issue in multiple view type recycler view i think the code in myadapter is lacking something which i am not able to figure out pls help. Here is the detailed description :

I have a response list from retrofit :

```
public class DateResponse {

@SerializedName("RecordEntryON")
@Expose
private String record_EntryOn;

@SerializedName("PatientID")
@Expose
private int Patient_ID;

@SerializedName("DiscountedAmount")
@Expose
private double discounted_Amount;

@SerializedName("ClientID")
@Expose
private int client_ID;

@SerializedName("TestType")
@Expose
private String test_Type;

@SerializedName("TestName")
@Expose
private String test_Name;

@SerializedName("FetchingTime")
@Expose
String fetching_Time;

@SerializedName("ClientTestCount")
@Expose
int clienttest_Count;

@SerializedName("CentreName")
@Expose
String center_Name;
```

getter and setter to follow (not writing here). I have another request model which i am passing into retrofit request here is the code for request model :

```
public class Date_Request {


@SerializedName("IsSuccess")
boolean is_success;

@SerializedName("Message")
String _message;

@SerializedName("ResponseData")
List<DateResponse> response_data;
```

code for retrofit in MyActivity :

```
 authToken = "Basic " + Utils.getAuthToken(Dashboard.this);
    restClient.getService().getByCentre(authToken, DEV_ID,defaultDate).enqueue(new 
Callback<Date_Request>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Date_Request> call, Response<Date_Request> response) {

         //   List<DateResponse> listAll;
            if (response.isSuccessful())
                try {
                   
                    boolean success = response.body().isIs_success();
                    String message = response.body().get_message();

                    if (success) {
                        listAll = response.body().getResponse_data();
                        List<DateResponse> centerList = new ArrayList<>();

                        int i;
                            for(i=0;i<5;i++){

                                String centerName = listAll.get(i).getCenter_Name();
                                int patientCount = listAll.get(i).getPatient_ID();
                                double amount = listAll.get(i).getDiscounted_Amount();

                                DateResponse topList = new DateResponse();


                       
                                topList.setPatient_ID(patientCount);
                                topList.setDiscounted_Amount(amount);
                                centerList.add(topList);

                              
  dateViewAdapter = new DateViewAdapter(centerList, Dashboard.this);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(dateViewAdapter);
                                dateViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
```

Procedure : I am selecting an option from Spinner there are three options: center,date,test. On select, a calendar opens user select the date and the corresponding list is shown. APIs for all three options are different with little different data. However, in model i am using only one response model and one request.

Now the issue is if I am running this code than no of item matches the for loop ie 5(or whatever i set here 10 15) and displayed in list if i remove the for loop and directly add the list wo setting getting anything here in activity than i still get list with 10 items as I fixed the list to show 10 items only using getItemCount method in adapter

1. **whatever I use center name is not showing(blank) + TextView hardcoded text of xml layout is not showing + I am unable to concatenate anything before center name.**
2. **The data--amount and patientCount is showing but no hardcoded text or cant concatenate anything with these fields**
3. **In the test or date list in the same recycler view test name is showing but not test type(blank) instead it is showing patient count in test list and date list also**

In centre list:

**centre name not showing
Patient Count and Amount showing but hardcoded text in textview missing in addition cant concatenate string Patient Count**

In test list:

**test name and amount is showing
test type is not showing instead patient count is showing**

In date list:
same as test list

Code for adapter :

```
public class DateViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<DateResponse> listAll;
private final int limit = 10;

private Context mContext;

private static final int CENTER_LIST = 0;
private static final int TEST_LIST = 1;
private static final int DATE_LIST = 2;
private static final int TYPE_DEFAULT = 3;

public DateViewAdapter(List<DateResponse> listAll, Context mContext) {
    this.listAll = listAll;
    this.mContext = mContext;

}

public void addAllItems(List<DateResponse> items) {
    listAll.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

//override getItemViewType method to assign the layout to each item depending on the viewtype passed


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    //   view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.center_list, parent, false);
    //   return new DetailsViewHolder(view);
    switch (viewType) {
        case CENTER_LIST:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.center_list, parent, false);
            return new CenterViewHolder(view);
        case TEST_LIST:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.test_list, parent, false);
            return new TestViewHolder(view);
        case DATE_LIST:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.date_list, parent, false);
            return new DateListViewHolder(view);
        default:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.default_view, parent, false);
            return new DefaultViewHolder(view);

    }


}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (listAll.get(position).toString().contains("CentreName")) {
        CenterViewHolder centerViewHolder = (CenterViewHolder) holder;
        centerViewHolder.setDetails(listAll.get(position));
      } else if (listAll.get(position).toString().contains("TestName")) {
          TestViewHolder testViewHolder = (TestViewHolder) holder;
          testViewHolder.setTestDetails(listAll.get(position));
      } else if (listAll.get(position).toString().contains("Date")) {
          DateListViewHolder dateListViewHolder = (DateListViewHolder) holder;
          dateListViewHolder.setDateListDetails(listAll.get(position));
      } else if (listAll.get(position).toString().contains("PatientID")) {
          DefaultViewHolder defaultViewHolder = (DefaultViewHolder) holder;
          defaultViewHolder.setDefaultDetails(listAll.get(position));

          // throw new RuntimeException("problem in logic");
      } else {
          throw new RuntimeException("problem in logic");
      }
}


public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    DateResponse dateResponse = new DateResponse();
    dateResponse = listAll.get(position);

    if(listAll.get(position).toString().contains("CentreName"))
    {
        return CENTER_LIST;
    } else if (listAll.get(position).toString().contains("TestName")) {
        return TEST_LIST;
    } else if (listAll.get(position).toString().contains("Date")) {
        return DATE_LIST;
    } else if (listAll.get(position).toString().contains("PatientID")) return TYPE_DEFAULT;
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (listAll.size() > limit) {
        return limit;
    } else {
        return listAll.size();
    }
}

class CenterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvCenterName, tvPatientCount, tvAmount;

    public CenterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvCenterName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cn_name);
        tvPatientCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pt_count);
        tvAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
    }

    void setDetails(DateResponse centerDetails) {


        tvCenterName.setText("Centre Name : " + centerDetails.getCenter_Name());
        tvPatientCount.setText("Patient Count : " + centerDetails.getPatient_ID());
        tvAmount.setText("Amount : " + centerDetails.getDiscounted_Amount());

    }
}


class TestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvTestName, tvTestType, tvTestAmount;

    public TestViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvTestAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_amount);
        tvTestName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_name);
        tvTestType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_type);

    }

    void setTestDetails(DateResponse testDetails) {
        tvTestType.setText("Test Name : " + testDetails.getTest_Type());
        tvTestName.setText(testDetails.getTest_Name());
        tvTestAmount.setText(String.valueOf(testDetails.getDiscounted_Amount()));
    }
}


class DateListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView tvClientCount, tvPatCount, tvDateAmount;

    public DateListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvClientCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.client_name);
        tvPatCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.patient_count);
        tvDateAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_test_amount);

    }

    void setDateListDetails(DateResponse dateListDetails) {
        tvDateAmount.setText(String.valueOf(dateListDetails.getDiscounted_Amount()));
        tvPatCount.setText(String.valueOf(dateListDetails.getPatient_ID()));
        tvClientCount.setText(dateListDetails.getTest_Name());
    }
}

class DefaultViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvdefaultCenter, tvdefaultCount, tvdefaultAmount;

    public DefaultViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvdefaultCenter = itemView.findViewById(R.id.default_center);
        tvdefaultCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.default_pt_count);
        tvdefaultAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.default_amount);

    }

    void setDefaultDetails(DateResponse defaultDetails) {
        tvdefaultCenter.setText(defaultDetails.getCenter_Name());
        tvdefaultCount.setText(String.valueOf(defaultDetails.getPatient_ID()));
        tvdefaultAmount.setText(String.valueOf(defaultDetails.getDiscounted_Amount()));
    }
}
```

}

layout for centre_list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/parent_linear"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/parent_matrix"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cp_info"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cn_name"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Centre Name : "
                android:textColor="@color/purple_200">
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="Patient Count : "
                android:id="@+id/pt_count"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="Amount"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Hey @tintin, I didn't understand your question. What is it doing that wasn't supposed to do? Could you please elaborate it better? Have you debugged you code to ensure if the network call is working properly? Is the data coming as expected?

Comment: @LennonSpirlandelli hi thanks for reply yes i have debugged and all is fine what I am doing -- selecting an option from spinner which shows three options center, test, date select an option calender will open select date from calender --sending that date to server which is providing response all is working fine as i said data is also showing in all list but the issue is fields are missing in center list there are three fields centername, patientcount and amount in this centername is missing similarly in test list test type is missing ....please tell if more info is required

Comment: In `itemViewType` you are comparing using `listAll.get(position).toString().toLowerCase().contains("centrename")`  while in `bindViewHolder` you are using `listAll.get(position).toString().contains("Centre")` - shouldn't both be same. Or better check viewholder in bindViewHolder also using  viewType - `if(holder.getItemViewType() == CENTER_LIST)`

Comment: Tintin are all the fields from center list missing or only a specific field? Same question with test list.
What @Nitish said makes sense if center list is not showing at all, but if only a specific field is not showing then I'd say to double check the fields you are getting from the api

Comment: @Nitish it is same for all ignore that line which you posted in the code see I have commented out the thing you are saying i pasted the code while working on this project it is same for all I was checking lowercase option when posted this sorry

Comment: @LennonSpirlandelli only center name is missing...amount and patient count is showing correct i checked in debug and also in postman entire list which is displaying in app is correct and matching api but centername is missing(blank) similarly in test list Test Type is missing(blank) .....when I removed multiple view and run the app showing only centerlist all fields were appearing correctly after adding multiple view it is messed up

Comment: What I can see is that in `onBindViewHolder` you are checking if contains `Centre` and on `getItemViewType` you check lowercase for `centrename`. Shouldn't they match? I'd say to use `if(getItemViewType(position) == CENTER_LIST)` inside `onBindViewHolder` so you reduce the chance of falling

Comment: @LennonSpirlandelli pls check i have updated the post included the procedure and also updated the adapter, data model code

Comment: @tintin you also aren't setting the centerName in your `onResponse`. You only set `patientCount` and `amount`

Comment: @LennonSpirlandelli did it ....i think it was deleted while posting here .....after debugging deep and trying different things....one thing is clear.....it is picking DateListViewHolder in every case ie why center name and other info is missing while selecting any other option....i concatenated string in set method of DateListViewHolder and it is showing in every case it means there is an issue in the getItemViewType() method.....